# Root being controlled by ARD

Tags: macos, osx-lion, root

I run a lab of 20 iMacs, all running Mac OS 10.7.5(11G63) with ARD version 3.6.2. My server and all of the iMacs run Lion. I seem to have crossed something and now my root user is being controlled with the same preferences I have setup for my LDAP users. Somehow, ARD has taken control of the root user, most notably the System Preferences.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: While I disagree with whoever voted this as off-topic (although it's borderline), I think you might get a better answer on Ask Different or even maybe Server Fault.  (That said, please don't cross-post - you can request migration if you don't get any good answers here.  And welcome to the site!)

Comment: I am curious if this better applies to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), it is definitely on the border of the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) for Super User (because it is somewhat of a specific IT problem, not home and personal networking.). Though I am not casting any votes since it's a moderator's decision.

Comment: I vote to leave it open, as it *is* within the guidelines, and he's not mentioning it's in a work environment, just a lab